# Basic schema design for notifications/feeds/requests?

Tags: database-design, social-networking

I am designing a social network and wanted to know if I am on the right track. I have Notifications, Requests and Live feeds on the site. Similar to what we see on most sites nowadays. To design these, I assume these are NOT separate components rather they all flow out from the same Activity component?

System has a set of say 200 activities possible involving 30 objects. 40 activities may have notifications, 70 may have feeds, 10 may have requests. So I assume these will be part of the activity look up table that is - does the activity have a Feed, Notification, Request as Boolean columns. If yes, then the default text to display for all 3 (Feed, Notification, Request) to the user like "NAME commented on  photo." Another column will be FK to the object look up table to match objects with activities.

So basically I am unsure if these should all be part of the activity look up table only or is there some other design to consider?

One possible use case is like notifications - the system may have 40 available but the user may only optin to 10 of those. So there will be a separate user settings table to hold user defined preferences.

Comment: A rather vague question, with so many related questions on "social network" / "database" / "design"...

Comment: Based on the simplicity of your design and rules, skip a DBMS.  It's overkill (and I'm a big fan of the classic DBMS).  Learn Cassandra now.  Notifications could be added and removed quickly from it, and it scales really well.  Otherwise, I don't think there is enough information here to really clarify what you are trying to do, but I'm hazarding a guess.

Comment: @Horus: I disagree. You shouldn't make things more complex just because they are so simple. A simple DB layer allows him to concentrate on issues that matter more, such as innovative features.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing sounds sane to me.  The activity relation seems usable in this case.  The big questions surround scale, but these can be solved by db solutions (Postgres-XC on Postgres for example).

I don't seen an obvious way to improve on the relational design there.